# Gcc compiler builtins constants

Tags: c, gcc

Do anyone know wht this code in stdarg.h do

What are these `__builtin_va_list`

And what do `__builtin_va_start(x,y) returns`

Answer (score 2):

These are GCC's builtins for implementing the [`stdarg.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) variadic function features.  The macros in `stdarg.h` expand to their `__builtin` equivalents, and the `__builtin` versions trigger the compiler to emit the appropriate code.

This allows the `stdarg.h` macros to behave in ways that couldn't easily be done in pure C or even inline assembly.

This is preferable to just having the compiler recognize the special identifiers `va_list`, `va_start`, etc, because it still allows the possibility for someone to rewrite those headers and implement them in their own way.  Or for extremely old code that predates the standard `stdarg.h` and might use the `va_*` identifiers for something else.

As a programmer, you normally shouldn't use them directly; use the standard `stdarg.h` types and macros instead: `va_list`, `va_start`, etc.

Comment: Ya but what does this __builtin_va_start(x,y) actually returns or do as it in needed in my os labs

Comment: @OSdev: It does the same thing as `va_start`, so read the standard documentation for that macro.  Even in OS programming you shouldn't use the `__builtin_*` versions; stdarg.h is part of the freestanding implementation and is safe to use in code that will run on bare metal with no OS or library support.  If someone is advising you to use the `__builtin` versions I would have to say they are misguided.

Comment: #define va_start(ap, last) __builtin_va_start(ap, last)

Comment: @OSdev: Yes, I know they define `va_start` as `__builtin_va_start`, that's what I said.  Don't read the headers to learn what they do, read the documentation.  E.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_start.  Or Section 7.16 of the C standard.  Or the [Linux stdarg manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg). Or any C textbook that discusses variadic functions.

Comment: And what do va_start exactly do i have read many sites but confused and microsoft reference is even hard

Comment: @OSdev: The links I've posted both contain examples that I think are pretty straightforward.  The purpose of `va_start` is, abstractly, to initialize a `va_list` object so that you can use it to retrieve arguments beyond the last named one. It doesn't return anything. What it actually does internally varies between platforms, and if that detail is important to you, you need to specify your platform and refer to its ABI.

Comment: @OSdev You might find [section 15](http://c-faq.com/varargs/index.html) of the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/) useful, or [this chapter](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11.html) of some online C notes.

Comment: I read a article from microsoft i am telling what i understood from it just point i am correct or not va_start, va_arg, va_end all these take a arg_ptr of type va list. These are used in functions with ... variable no of argument in which va_start make arg_ptr point to first argument, va_arg retrieves value of that argument and va_end amkes arg_ptr value null. Am i correct

Comment: @OSdev: Yes, this is basically correct.